# How to pass array items through state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am making a card game and want the playCard to contain both previous and additional cards inside the array. Currently when I try to use pop or splice from player hand it will take those cards from the player hand array and put them in the playCard array but when player2 tries to add to the playCard array it overwrites it and only has player2 card inside. This is how I am creating the cards and dealing them:

```
  this.state = {
            deck: [],
            player1: [],
            player2: [],
            player3: [],
            player4: [],
            playCard: [],

        }

        this.makeCards(); 
        this.shuffle();

    }

    makeCards = () => {
        const suits = ['Hearts', 'Spades', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds']
        const values = ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']


        for (let suit in suits){
            for (let value in values) {
                this.state.deck.push(<span className='cards' key={value+suit}>{values[value]}</span>);
            }
        }

        return this.deck
    }

    deal = () => {
            this.setState({ player1: this.state.deck.filter((cards, index) => {
                    return index < 13 ? cards : null
                }) 
            }) 
            this.setState({ player2: this.state.deck.filter((cards, index) => {
                    return index >= 13 && index < 26 ? cards : null
                }) 
            }) 
            this.setState({ player3: this.state.deck.filter((cards, index) => {
                    return index >= 26 && index < 39 ? cards : null
                }) 
            }) 
            this.setState({ player4: this.state.deck.filter((cards, index) => {
                    return index >= 39 && index <= 52 ? cards : null
                }) 
            }) 
    }
```

choseCard function places the first card in player1 array to the playCard, but when player2turn happens it changes to the one card from the player2 array.

```
 choseCard(){
        this.setState(() => ({playCard: this.state.player1.splice(0,1)}))

    }
    player2turn() {

        this.setState(() => ({playCard: this.state.player2.splice(0,1)}))
        //I need to filter player2 array to find card value in playCard
        //if it has that then push to this.state.playCard
        //Player 3 sorts through array to find card etc....
    }
```

I understand there is no filtering happening now I just want player2 to add to the playCard array. How do I do that while still taking the cards from the player array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.setState(({ playCard, player2 }) => {
  return {
   playCard: [...playCard, ...player2.slice(0, 1)],
   player2: [...player2.slice(1, player2.length - 1)],
  };
});
```

Combine the previous state with the new one and don't mutate it. If you need to change player2 also, just create a new array based on prev state without the first card.

Comment: This works correctly when I use splice instead of slice, as im taking the card away from the player and putting it in the playCard array. Thank you!

Comment: @3bag the splice mutates referenced array. You would better create a new one and update the state.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a copy of the state value to manipulate. Otherwise you will directly manupilate the arrays. Try something like this. It will create a copy. Manpulate the array and then place them back in state.

```
choseCard(){
  let player1 = [ ...this.state.player1 ]
  let playCard = player1.splice[0,2]
  this.setState(() => ({player1, playCard}))
}
player2turn() {
  let player1 = [ ...this.state.player1 ]
  let playCard = [ player1.pop() ]
  this.setState(() => ({player1, playCard}))
  //I need to filter player2 array to find card value in playCard
  //if it has that then push to this.state.playCard
  //Player 3 sorts through array to find card etc....
}
```

Comment: When I use slice it wont take the card from the player array but when I use `this.state.player1.splice(0, 1)`
it does take it out, but when player2 splice(0, 1) the playCard array still is only 1 card even tho 2 cards have been taken from the players..

Comment: I updated my answer. Just use a copy of the state and then re-set the player hands once you are done manipulating them. The basic issue was you were manipulating the arrays in state which cause really bad and weird things to happen. This is just one way to solve this.